# Unexpected error while switching activities in android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I'm making a splash screen in my android app, but if I attempt to start an activity in Run() I get that the error of application has stopped unexpectedly, if I use setContentView instead of startActivity, the error happens too, Even if I use SplashScreen.this.startActivity instead of only startActivity I get error. I tryed to use TimerTask instead of handler but it happens the same, what am I doing wrong?

```
package name.appname;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity{
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(getRunnableStartApp(), 1500);
  }//public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

 public Runnable getRunnableStartApp(){
    return new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));//when i quit this line, no error happens...
            finish();
        }//public void run()
    };//new Runnable()
 }//public Runnable getRunnableStartApp()
}//public class SplashScreen extends Activity
```

This is the Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="name.appname"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:allowBackup="false" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="SplashScreen"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I catched the error: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException, but no know why happens that

Comment: show us your manifest file. made an entry for the activities in manifest?

Comment: Which error or exception are you getting..?

Comment: Typically, you use Runnable and Run() to start an activity in a new thread. If you don't need the new thread, then startactivity should suffice: when the new activity finishes, the 'starting' activity (SplashScreen) will  receive focus again. Does this meet your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below in manifest file. Missing entry for MainActivity

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Also change this

```
<activity android:name="name.appname.SplashScreen"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Note: Some people consider using splash screen as evil if it does nothing. Check the below

http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Comment: im going to make that splash loads info, dont care Raghunandan

Comment: i just posted the link as a suggestion if you are fine with splash go ahead with it

Answer (score 0):

Use Runnable inside Timertask.
I have also SplashScreen for my app & it works fine.

Comment: why do you think timer and timertask is better instead of handler?

Comment: handler ist better, enything else ist creating objects you dont need

Comment: I know handler is better than timer.